# Get row value from different column if current column has "zero length string" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a user_table and the columns are like -> user_name, login_name, first_name, last_name

So I am doing

```
select CONCAT(FIRST_NAME," ",LAST_NAME) as displayName
```

This will give me a concatinated string in displayName, but the problem is, for some users, FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME is NULL, so but LOGIN_NAME is filled, so I want to get the value from LOGIN_NAME if the FIRST_NAME OR LAST_NAME is empty. Can I do this with CASES or anyone knows a better approach.

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are using.  I removed the SQL Server tag, because SQL Server does not recognize `" "` as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest (and most self-documenting) would be to make sure both first name and last name are not NULL and not a zero-length string (what "empty" means is less clear but this should cover both):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FIRST_NAME > '' AND LAST_NAME > ''
  THEN CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME)
  ELSE LOGIN_NAME
END AS displayName
```

Comment: . . If you use `CONCAT()`, then this will work in both SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, missed that it was tagged incorrectly.\

Comment: Giving me empty value since field is empty (first_name and last_name is empty) so it is not picking login_name instead

Comment: @sh4r4d Does "empty" mean a zero-length string? That is different from `NULL`. Please show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: FIRST_NAME AND LAST_NAME can be NULL

Comment: It worked, I am surprised how coalesce is not working!

Comment: @sh4r4d Because you seem to be confusing `NULL` and zero-length string. They are *not* the same, and `COALESCE` only cares about the former.

Answer (score 3):

use coalesce() it will return 1st non null value

```
select CONCAT(coalesce(FIRST_NAME,LOGIN_NAME),' ',LAST_NAME) as displayName
```

I'm assuming incase of 1st name null last name also null other than that use below approach

```
SELECT IF(FIRST_NAME is null and LAST_NAME is null , LOGIN_NAME, 
CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' ',LAST_NAME)) as displayName
```

Answer (score 0):

in mysql can use ifnull() and in sqlserver can use isnull()

```
select CONCAT(ifnull(FIRST_NAME,'')," ",ifnull(LAST_NAME,'')," " ,ifnull(login_name,'')) as displayName
```